# What could be causing the lower branches of my hydroponic tomato's to die

Tags: tomatoes, hydroponic

I'm using Masterblend nutrients and am changing nutrient solution every two weeks, my EC and PH have been good and stable yet the lower branches die one at a time.[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could post a photo of the plant (and the setup)

Answer (score 0):

The plant seems to be a lot less vigorous than we might hope for; since the growing conditions appear to be ideal and not exposed in a field situation we might suspect a nutrition problem. It is part of the normal growing process for the plant to steal from the oldest leaves to feed the emerging young leaves if necessary. Examine the dying leaves for signs of disease and if this is eliminated then watch for signs such as deficiencies which can show up in various ways.

Focusing on nutrient we hypothesize that even though the food mix starts out well it is not getting to the growing point efficiently. Was the nutrient mix thoroughly mixed, and is there anything in the water supply that might cause elements to be precipitated out chemically causing a layer to appear at the bottom of the settling tank? If the plants were in a field situation we could suspect a borer at soil level which physically slows the translocation of nutrient into the top of the plant.

It would be instructive to sacrifice one sick plant to an autopsy to assess the progress of roots, stem and leaves - look for woodiness in the stem which indicates premature aging and cells that provide support but are not efficient conductors of fluids.